# Probability of 100,000 Computer parts, if one computer part lasts more than seven years is $0.4966$

Tags: probability, exponential-distribution

If the length of time the computer part lasts is exponentially distributed with mean value is $10$.

So, for the exponential distribution, we can find the probability of one computer parts.

$$p(x>7) = e^{(-m * 7)} = 0.4966$$
where $m = \frac{1}{mean} = 0.1$.

[image]

My question, what is probability of $100000$ computer parts lasts more than seven years ?

Comment: The probability all $100000$ parts last $7$ years? Very very small. There is only a $0.1\%$ chance they will all last $6$ hours

Comment: @Henry, thanks, could you please explain with solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming their lifespan is independepent, and they are all exponentially distributed like you say,

$P(\text{all parts make it}) = \prod_{p\in\text{all products}}\exp(-m\cdot7) = \exp(-m\cdot 7)^{100000}$

First step is independence, second step is rewriting the same thing.

It's just the number you have, 0.49, multiplied with itself 100000 times, $$0.49\cdot0.49\cdot\ \dots\ \cdot0.49$$.

Comment: Thanks, if we include total lifespan is 100000, then, how would be the result looks like?

Comment: Result is 0, if $0.49^{100000}$

Comment: Yes, it's zero for a computer (due to rounding) and for all practical purposes.